# i am building app using cordova when i try to login from app i am getting cors error how to solve this

Tags: cordova, mobile

i am building app using cordova when  i try to login from app i am getting cors error how to solve this its showing Access to fetch at from origin 'https://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

i have tried to add meta tag in index.html and i have added <access origin "*" /> config.xml and

Comment: the problem seems to be in the api file situated in the server. please mention both of your codes to check.

Comment: <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="about:*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <platform name="ios">
        <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
        <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    </platform>. this is my config.xml file

Comment: <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:supportsRtl="true" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

Comment: no no no ....not the config.xml file... it has got nothing to do with that... are you using react, angular or jquery? please mention that code and the server side api code

Comment: I am using angular

Comment: unless you provide with a detailed information no body here will be able to help you. it's nothing to do with your config.xml file. what's your server side? php? asp?

Comment: Hi Riya Singh
  I have fixed this issue it is in the config.xml file only. this is what i have changed its working fine

Comment: <platform name="android">
    <preference name="scheme" value="app" />
    <preference name="hostname" value="localhost" />
    <preference name="MixedContentMode" value="2" />
    <preference name="Scheme" value="http" />
</platform>

Comment: I am glad to see that it worked... it usually isn't config.xml file for the error you specified.